# Javascript get image size onload

Tags: javascript

I saw similar post about my problem but they only display width and height. But I have to return these variables to use them later.

here is my code, I get always "0" ;

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "my_image.jpg";
newWidth = 0;
wnewHeight = 0;
img.onload = function() {
newWidth = (img.width*0.5);
newHeight = (img.height*0.5);
//return [newWidth , newHeight];
}

alert (newWidth);
```

Comment: please see at; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `img`.

Also, you need to put the alert inside the callback function as the image is loaded asynchronously.  So

```
 var img = new Image();
    img.src = "my_image.jpg";
    newWidth = 0;
    wnewHeight = 0;
    img.onload = function() {
    newWidth = (this.width*0.5);
    newHeight = (this.height*0.5);

    alert (newWidth);

    return [newWidth , newHeight];
    }
```

Comment: @bourax, there was a mistake in my answer, try it now

Comment: I tried this before and it works fine, this is what I told.But, I don't want to display, I want to be able to use them later (out of the function)

Comment: You can return empty object and then in load add height and width properties. Or use callback.

Comment: @bourax "*I want to be able to use them later (out of the function)*" -- Have your `onload` function call another function. Or have `onload` set a boolean flag (like `hasLoaded`) that indicates whether the images has loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it. I handled the onload return in a variable X:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "my_image.jpg";
newWidth = 0;
wnewHeight = 0;
var x = img.onload = function() {
newWidth = (this.width*0.5);
newHeight = (this.height*0.5);
return [newWidth , newHeight];
}();
alert (x[0]); //for the weight
alert (x[1]); //for the height
```

Comment: This only works when the image loads immediately and no `onload` is needed. That only happens when the image has been loaded previously and is already in the browser's cache. You are not even setting `img.onload` to a function; you are setting it to an array. Try out your code with an image you haven't loaded recently (or do a hard refresh with Ctrl+Shift+R) and you'll see that it does not work for initial loads. For example, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5LzacLz7/

Comment: owww that's true ?? so how do I fix it ??